# TFVC to Git - build duplicating previously ignored linked files that Git picks up

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, azure-devops, tfvc

My org is moving a fifty or so project code repository over from an on-premise shared TFS 2015 instance with TFVC to Azure DevOps and Git.

I completed a tip migration successfully, checking out the current branch from TFS onto my hard drive, creating a new local Git repo (with a .gitignore), added, and committed the local files into a master branch  pushed to Azure DevOps.

Switching directories I connected via Visual Studio 2017 to the new repository and cloned it backed down to an empty directory and started building solutions. For one particular solution that includes a MVC web front end app and a Web.API backend app with several class libraries that had to be built first. The main build for the solution ran successfully.

After the build, Git status reported there were several hundred new un-tracked files in the Web project that turned out to be from the class libraries. Looking at the properties within the Solution Explorer they are all linked files pointing to the correct library project and are marked to not be copied to output folder on build. Editing one, updates the other and vice versa.

I blew away all the files and local Git repository and ran the clone and build process all over again to verify that the files came over during the build process only.

Adding the duplicate files (hundreds!) to .gitignore works of course to keep from double entry, but my question is what drove these to show up in Git when they've never been an issue in TFVC and are there other options besides .gitignore to keep these files from being duplicated in the repository. I haven't found any reference to this issue elsewhere.

All in the Windows world as you might expect.

Edit: In the end I added several full directories to .gitignore and moved on and have since left the company and can't pursue this farther.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with your `.gitignore`. Can you share your current `.gitignore`?

Comment: The project is using the .gitignore from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Were these files checked in during the migration?  Do they appear as “new” or “untracked” files or are they “modified”?

Comment: The originals, in the class libraries outside the direct solution path, were checked in, after the build they appeared as "untracked" in the application project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add the `.gitignore` for you particular language/IDE from https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: The standard .gitignore was part of the solution from the start - but this is excellent advice